# Dynamically Selecting Dropdown Options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown option on a page. which is loading on a button click. All the fields are filling but the dropdown is not getting selected.

This is the dropdown field

```
<select id="id_select_branch" placeholder="select branch" onfocusout="branch_validation();" required="">
  <option value="-1">Please Select working branch</option>
  <option value="bandhan konnagar">bandhan konnagar</option>
  <option value="bandhan konnagar_HO">bandhan konnagar_HO</option>
</select>
```

This is what I have tried..

```
$("#id_select_branch").val(row.current_branch);
```

Second Approach..

```
$("#id_select_branch option[value='"+row.current_branch+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Third Aprroach..

```
    var branch_value = JSON.stringify(row.current_branch);
    var element = document.getElementById("id_select_branch");
    console.log(element);
    SelectElement(element, branch_value);
    function SelectElement(element, branch_value)
      {    
         for(var i=0; i<element.options.length; i++ )
            {

              if(element.options[i].text == branch_value )
             {
             element.options[i].selected = true;
                        return;
              }
             }
     }
```

Note: row.current_branch is the text value which will be matched with the dropdown and will be selected

Comment: Your code works fine. Try to check `console.log(row.current_branch)` if it match any value in the select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` to check if your `<option>` have required value or not . i.e :

```js
var yourtext="bandhan konnagar";
//checking if option have the value define 
$("#id_select_branch").find("option[value='"+yourtext+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id_select_branch" placeholder="select branch" onfocusout="branch_validation();" required="">
  <option value="-1">Please Select working branch</option>
  <option value="bandhan konnagar">bandhan konnagar</option>
  <option value="bandhan konnagar_HO">bandhan konnagar_HO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Will It also work for

<option value="-1">Please Select working branch</option>
  <option value="1">bandhan konnagar</option>
  <option value="2">bandhan konnagar_HO</option>

Comment: @Swati if the text is just `bandhan konnagar`, it still select the `bandhan konnagar_HO`.

Comment: @Cuong Le Ngoc that I can set dynamically. But Contains still didn't solve my problem

Comment: @Swati the same that Cuong stated..
Even if my text is just bandhan konnagar, it selects bandhan konnagar_HO. I think it is because contains is matching both the strings.